# send email using java bold text of message body

Tags: java, email

i want to send email using java for recover password. now i want to bold my message only verification code. how to i bold my code.

String messageText = " Welcome to Smart application system. "+"Your verification code is : "+GenerateVerificationCode+" "+" Submit your veirfication code to verify your account.";

Comment: Also add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: To insert bold (as well as other text styles) you should consider the possibility of using HTML in body instead of plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the mimetype of the mail body to HTML and format your content using HTML tags for bold: <B>